# How to set custom name for RabbitMQ connection?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

It would be useful to be able to identify the RabbitMQ client by its connection name.

I'm using Spring Cloud Streams abstraction and with default settings I getting something like that:

[image]

How can I set a custom RabbitMQ connection name in my Spring Boot client?

---

### EDIT

#### Spring Boot 1.7+

This is solution based on Gary Russell's answer:

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration {
    private final String instanceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8); // TODO: Environment/Consul/Eureka
    private final String connectionNamePrefix;
    private AtomicInteger connectionNumber = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public MessagingConfiguration(@Value("${custom.rabbitmq.connection-name-prefix:SpringBootApp}") String connectionNamePrefix) {
        this.connectionNamePrefix = connectionNamePrefix;
    }

    private String generateConnectionName() {
        return connectionNamePrefix + '#' + instanceId + ':' +  connectionNumber.getAndIncrement();
    }

    @Bean
    public SmartInitializingSingleton reconfigureConnectionFactory(final AbstractConnectionFactory cf) {
        return () -> cf.setConnectionNameStrategy(f -> generateConnectionName());
    }
}
```

It works with the [default configuration](https://github.com/wildloop/streams-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-1vh.yml), but doesn't work for a [multiple systems connection](https://github.com/wildloop/streams-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-2vh.yml).

#### Spring Boot 2.0.1+

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration {
    private final String instanceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8); // TODO: Environment/Consul/Eureka
    private final String connectionNamePrefix;
    private AtomicInteger connectionNumber = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public MessagingConfiguration(@Value("${custom.rabbitmq.connection-name-prefix:SpringBootApp}") String connectionNamePrefix) {
        this.connectionNamePrefix = connectionNamePrefix;
    }

    private String generateConnectionName() {
        return connectionNamePrefix + '#' + instanceId + ':' +  connectionNumber.getAndIncrement();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionNameStrategy defineConnectionNameStrategy() {
        return connectionFactory -> generateConnectionName();
    }
}
```

Note, there is a [bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1541) in a multi-binder scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with version <strike>2.0</strike> 1.7 (see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#connections)) you can provide a `ConnectionNameStrategy`...

```
@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    cf.setConnectionNameStrategy(f -> "myConnectionName");
    return cf;
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The strategy can be set any time before the connection is opened. If, say, you want to use Spring Boot's auto configured factory (which is used by Spring Cloud Stream by default), you could do something like this...

```
@Bean
public SmartInitializingSingleton reconfigureCf(final CachingConnectionFactory cf) {
    return () -> cf.setConnectionNameStrategy(f -> "myName");
}
```

This will be run before anything is `start()`ed.

Actually it was backported to [1.7.x](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-684).

Comment: Thanks, but in this way I must create own ConnectionFactory, configure it etc. I just want to inject my ConnectionNameStrategy, nothing more. Is  there any way to do it?

Comment: Thank you for the magic :)
It works with [default configuration](https://github.com/wildloop/streams-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-1vh.yml), but doesn't work when I use [connection to multiple systems](https://github.com/wildloop/streams-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-2vh.yml).
Is there any chance to add autoconfiguration support for something like this property: `spring.rabbitmq.connection-name-prefix`?

Comment: That requires a change to boot since each of those binders gets loaded into a separate application context. I have [issued a pull request against boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/12339) if you want to track it.

Comment: BTW, it looks like [multiple-systems configuration](https://github.com/wildloop/streams-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-2vh.yml) always inherit default environment with `Spring Boot 2.0` and and `Spring Cloud Finchley.M8`. It works OK with `Spring Boot 1.5.9` and `Spring Cloud Edgware.SR2` on same configuration. Where should I post this issue?

Comment: I would start with stream. An example the exhibits the behavior will help.

Comment: A custom `ConnectionNameStrategy` is ignored if there is a custom binder configuration: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1541